# Will collection contains documents belongs to different cluster

Tags: java, marklogic-9

Group of documents is nothing but collection in mark logic.Will collection contains documents belongs to different cluster.For example I have 2 documents ,document 1 is present in Cluster 1 and document 2 is present in cluster 2, can I make it as a one collection

Answer (score 0):

No, not in a useful way. You can assign the same collection to any document anywhere, but you can't access them together, unless they are in the same Database. Databases cannot include forests from hosts in a foreign cluster, nor have a sub-database from a foreign cluster.

You could in theory have a cluster span hosts in different regions, if that is what you are aiming at, but that is bad practice. Database replication, or FlexRep might be of interest to you though. Hard to tell without knowing more though. It always helps to elaborate on the background a bit, tell why you are trying to do this..

HTH!